# PHP get_meta_tags() Function truncates results

Tags: php

I am trying to fetch website keywords with `get_meta_tags()` function.
But it returns truncated results. How I can get full results?

It gives me like this
Mycode --- >

```
print_r(get_meta_tags('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=__dTmkodoYU'));
```

Result --- >

```
[keywords] => play doh, hello kitty, Hello Kitty (Fictional Character), kinder, Kinder Surprise (Consumer Product), kinder surprise eggs, peppa pig, peppa pig kinder surpr...
```

After certain amount of characters it puts dot dot dot. I want full.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get_meta_tags()` is returning exactly what it sees on the page. If you "View Source" on that page, you'll find it's truncated there too:

```
<meta name="keywords" content="play doh, hello kitty, Hello Kitty (Fictional
  Character), kinder, Kinder Surprise (Consumer Product), kinder surprise eggs,
  peppa pig, peppa pig kinder surpr...">
```

If you want *all* of the tags for that video, you'll need to find another way of retrieving them (e.g, using the YouTube API). They aren't present in the "keywords" meta tag.

Answer (score 0):

`print_r` will truncate the strings that are too long. Instead, you should print them yourself:

```
$tags = get_meta_tags('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=__dTmkodoYU');
foreach ($tags as $k => $v) {
    echo htmlentities($k) . ' = ' . htmlentities($v) . '<br/>';
}
```

Comment: if I do 
var_dump($tags);die();
I still get truncated string. I think there is character limit on the function. But I can't find the arguments for it.

Comment: Where did you get that idea? `print_r()` does no such thing; it'll happily print out pages and pages of data if you ask it to.

Comment: @duskwuff, looks like you're right. I remember there's a dump function that used to annoy me because it was truncating strings. Might be from Xdebug or something like this.